# How to Upload a CSV File in Background Process with PHP (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I want to build a functionality in Laravel 5.8 that can help me to upload a CSV file and import the data into database, but it all should be in background(server side) process and once it is completed send an email to the logged in user. I want to get a better understanding before I start the process should I do this with a help of `Scheduler` or there would be a better way or library that can help me to achieve this functionality.

Looking forward to hear your thoughts :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from scratch:

Create a `invoices` table and the corresponding model:

> php artisan make:model Invoice -m

Your model should look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'invoices';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'processed',
        'path'
    ];

    public function scopeNotProcessed(Builder $query)
    {
        return $this->where('processed', '=', false);
    }
}
```

And here is the `invoices` table:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('path')->nullable(false);
        $table->boolean('processed')->default(false)->nullable(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

After get those things done, proceed as follows:

Create a repository, what will upload your csv file. This file should be placed at
`app/Repositories/CSVRepository`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Invoice;

class CSVRepository {

    /**
     * CSVRepository constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * @param $file
     * @param $extension
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function uploadCSV($file, $extension){
        return $this->upload($file, $extension);
    }

    /**
     * @param $file
     * @param $extension
     * @return mixed 
     */
    private function upload($file, $extension){
        $path = Storage::putFileAs("myFileName", $file, uniqid().".".$extension);
        $uploadedFile = Invoice::create([
            'path' => $path,
            'processed' => false,
        ]);

        return $uploadedFile;
    }
}
```

Now, create your controller, that will upload the file to the server using the `CSVRepository`:
The upload function should looks like this one:

```php
public function upload(CSVRepository $CSVRepository)
{
    try{
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $extension = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
        if ($extension !== 'csv'){
            $errors['file'] = 'This is not a .csv file!';
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($errors);
        }
        $CSVRepository->uploadCSV($file, $extension); 
        $message = array(
            'type' => 'success',
            'text' => 'Your file has been uploaded! You will receive an email when processing is complete!',
            'title' => 'Success',
        );
        session()->flash('message', $message);
        return redirect('route-to-redirect');
    }catch (\Exception $exception){
        return abort(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 'Internal Server Error');
    }
}
```

Now, you need a job, which process the file to you:

Start creating a command with the artisan command:

> php artisan make:command ProcessCSVCommand

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Invoice;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ProcessCSVCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'csv:process';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Process an uploaded CSV file';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try{
            //Retrieve only no processed files:
            $invoices = Invoice::notProcessed()->get();
            if (count($invoices) < 1){
                $this->info('No files found');
                return;
            }
            //Process the files:
            $invoices->map(function($invoice){ 
                $file = fopen("storage/app/".$invoice->path, "r");
                while (!feof($file)){
                    $line = fgets($file); 
                    //Here you have a loop to each line of the file, and can do whatever you need with this line:
                    if(strlen($line) > 0){ //If the line is not empty:
                        // Add your logic here:
                    }
                    // Don't forgot to change your `processed` flag to true:
                    $invoice->processed = true;
                    $invoice->save(); 
                } 
            });
        }catch (\Exception $exception){
            $this->error("Something went wrong");
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, open your `app/Console/Kernel.php` file:

Register your new command in the `$commands` array:

```php
$commands = [
    Commands\ProcessCSVCommand::class,
];
```

Schedule a job that runs on your server, checking for files to be processed and, if so, processing them:

In the same file, now at the `schedule` function:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('csv:process')
              ->everyFiveMinutes();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Queue's are the way to go for this kind of work. Uploading the file essentially needs to happen in that one request, but past that, you can create a queue/s that will chip away at converting the CSV into records in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to consider using Queues and listening for the job processed event as mentioned here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-events from where you can then send your mail